# Retrieving data from facebook in a winform

Tags: .net, facebook

I understand that using the facebook API I need an api key to connect, but I still don't understand how i would go about doing this, and how can i retrieve information upon users using the API (i'm only interested in retrieving the information that is publicly available e.g: username, birthdate, and other info that a specific user left public)

I downloaded the facebook development kit, and tried adding the FacebookService control, but i don't get it...
All the examples/samples i found on the internet are older than the version i have and therefore work a little different..

Can someone please post an example of how i would connect, using a certain API key, and retrieve someones public info/public photos (if there are any) ??

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should spend some time reading the [Facebook Developer Wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Main_Page).** Facebook development requires understanding how facebook applications are structured and how developers must configure them with the Facebook site to get them to work. You can't just drop a control in your app and expect to be able to get it to work.

The wiki has articles that explain how to get a developer ID, what FBML is, what an API key is, and so forth. If you plan to do any serious FB development, the wiki is an excellent resource.

There is a [good article here](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-use-the-facebook-developer-toolkit-20/) about setting up a profile and using FB toolikit to create an application. Perhaps that can help get you a quicker start.

Answer (score 0):

I won't talk about the .NET way of doing it since this is regarding to how to get the API key from Facebook.

1. Login to Facebook [**Developers**](http://www.facebook.com/developers/) page (using your Facebook credentials). In there, create an Application. Once successful, Facebook will provide you an `Application ID` and `Application Secret`. You will need the 2 to use the Facebook API. **Never** show these details to anyone else anybody can use it for malicious purposes.
2. Follow the [**Facebook API**](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API) to understand what methods to call and what the API expects in order to make the call successful.

Follow an example here (http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/facebook-java-api-example-to-publish-on-wall/) on how to create a Facebook Application.