# How can I access social networking sites from a .NET WinForms application?

Tags: .net, winforms, facebook

Is there any way that exists to access Facebook from a .NET WinForms application?

I want to develop an application in .NET (either C# or VB.NET) which can access Facebook.

Comment: Did you try to search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+.net

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596234/retrieving-data-from-facebook-in-a-winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice idea...
There are actually several ways, since facebook is publishing the service as API, you can try researching their API.

However the most common way of getting a page is either using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse or WebClient. It will download the HTML code where the HTML will load another page (I am guessing here, since facebook is heavily using ajax).

So after retrieving HTML page from facebook, what you need to is checking what page/service is facebook trying to retrieve, then you can get it using above method. This is hardcore programmer though...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an application doing just that.

[Silverlight Facebook client](http://www.telerik.com/products/facedeck.aspx)

After checking it out to see an application doing it, execute the search suggested above to start figuring out how to do it yourself.